# Emacs switch-to-buffer (C-x b) will change window if the buffer is opened in some other window

Tags: emacs

I would like to change the behavior of switch-to-buffer to always open the desired buffer in the current window instead of switching to another window if already opened.

My rationale for doing this :
I have 2 screens, one Emacs on each. One is for reading, the other one for writing. Some buffers will be in the reading side for a while, but now I want to edit them. I'd like to have them in front of me instead of automatically switch to this other window on the side.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That is what `switch-to-buffer` does - exactly what you say you want. Do you see something different when you start Emacs without an init file (`emacs -Q`)?

The only exception is when the window cannot be used for that buffer.  As the doc string says:

> If the selected window cannot display the specified
>   buffer (e.g. if it is a minibuffer window or strongly dedicated
>   to another buffer), call `pop-to-buffer' to select the buffer in
>   another window.

Comment: thank you for this insightful answer, iswitchb might be to blame for this behavior.

Comment: Recursively bisect your init file to determine the culprit. It is very quick to do. Comment out 1/2 of it, then 3/4, then 7/8,... (You can use command `comment-region`, and with `C-u` uncomments.)